# on hover image is shaking in FF Chrome but not in IE10

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am expanding both sides of an image on hover.It works perfect in IE 10 but not in FF and Chrome.The image shakes while expanding.
Not sure if it is css or browser issue.Here is the code which I am using

HTML -

```
<div class="welcome-message-1">
    <div class="expanding-block expanding-block-a content-left desktop-left">
        <div class="expanding-block-inner">
            <img class="expanding-block-background" src="http://demo-pinksquid.co.uk/fiddletest/1319512_orig.jpg" />
            <img class="expanding-block-background-contracted" src="http://demo-pinksquid.co.uk/fiddletest/1319512_orig.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
<p>dsadsadasd</p>
```

CSS

```
.expanding-block-a {
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto 2px;
    max-width: 1030px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}
.expanding-block-a .expanding-block-inner {
    height: 245px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -550px;
    margin-top: -110px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1100px;
}
.expanding-block-a .expanding-block-background-contracted {
    display: block;
    width: 1100px;
}
p {
    height:50px;
}
.expanding-block-a.hover, .no-js .expanding-block-a:hover {
    max-width: 1100px;
    height: 245px;
}
.expanding-block-a .expanding-block-background {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 1100px;
}
.expanding-block-a.hover .expanding-block-background, .no-js .expanding-block-a:hover .expanding-block-background {
    display: block;
}
```

jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.expanding-block-a').hover(

    function () {
        $('.expanding-block').addClass("hover");
    },

    function () {
        $('.expanding-block').removeClass("hover");
    });
});
```

The interesting part is if there is no browser scrollbar then it works perfect in all browser.Once you get the scrollbar it starts shaking.For debug purpose I have added few paragraphs to see.

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fAm6V/1/

**Please reduce the html/javascript window bar in jsfiddle so you get the full image view.**

Comment: must be something seriously wrong for something to work in IE over FF & chrome! lol

Comment: I get it to work in Chrome ok, but FF not. It seems to be the margin auto that is causing the problem, but not sure why. If you change that to just 20px or something the transition works smoothly. see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F9TkT/2/

Comment: lol...now we stop complaining about IE.He is a good guy only in this case.

Comment: Dave thanks for pointing it out.But if you see my demo only the sides are expanding not the entire img.I just checked yours one.The whole image is moving.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra yeah, that's just because I changed the margin to 20px. That possibly explains what is happening. For every px you are expanding the margin: auto has to recalculate. That may be the explanation for the jumping around.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 2px you have on the following CSS:

```
.expanding-block-a {
    height: 245px;
    margin: 0 auto 2px;  /*<-- remove 2px from here */
    max-width: 1030px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the transition work smoothly.
[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/F9TkT/3/)

Comment: Sorry but it's still moving in ff and chrome.

Comment: Is it 2px to add or remove?

Comment: The scrollbar is the culprit here.Unfortunately I cannot put margin-left as my header is full window width.

Comment: That's alright.I am using 1920px wide monitor.It's shaking there but in my laptop it works great.Strange.